# Создаются переносы строк, если строка длинная и редактируется. Как отключить?

Tags: phpstorm

Собственно сабж - phpStorm сам создаёт переносы строк, если строка длинная и редактируется. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно отключить?

Answer (score 7):

Как отключить перенос строк рассказано в [справке](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/general.html):

```
File | Settings | Раздел  Project Settings | Code Style - General - Wrap when typing reaches right margin
```

Comment: спасибо, сработало!

Comment: у меня другое меню Editor | Code Style -> General [Wrap on typing]